# VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010) - MS Outlook

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I have email automation, but when it opens up the outlook screen, the outlook window has a topmost function in it and I can't go back to my program. ANy thoughts?

```
Dim oOutL As New Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oAddSig As Outlook.Inspector

oMail = oOutL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
'oMail.UnRead = True
oMail.To = Me.P_emailTextBox.Text
oMail.Subject = "Blah"
'oMail.HTMLBody = True
oAddSig = oMail.GetInspector

oMail.Body = "Dear " & Me.P_titleTextBox.Text & " " & Me.P_firstTextBox.Text & " " &     Me.P_lastTextBox.Text & "," & oMail.Body


oMail.Display(True)

'oMail.SendUsingAccount = "blah@blah.com"


Return
```

Comment: Programmers use at least two monitors.  Using the remote debugger is a band-aid.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm hoping this comment was meant for another message, because I don't see any mention of using a remote debugger or a single monitor. Plus, sometimes developers have no choice but to use a single monitor (laptop on a plane, lack of funds to purchase a second monitor, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are displaying the outlook mail item modally (passing true to the `Display` method).

If you need to work in your program, you should pass False and then set a breakpoint in your program so that you can inspect what you need to inspect.

Comment: Well that was easy enough! Thank you!